# Page should be reloaded on submitting the button

Tags: php, reload

I have the following php code:-

```
 <?php
   .....
   ......
   if(isset($_POST['disable']))
   {
 foreach ( $_POST['users'] as $userid ) {
 $wpdb->query("UPDATE ".$wpdb->prefix."usercontrol SET disable_status ='disabled'
     WHERE ID = ".$wpdb->escape($userid));
 } 
   }
  ?>

    HTMl
    -----
   <input type="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Disable'); ?>" name="disable" 
   id="disable" class="button-secondary action" />
```

This is the page:-
[image]

I need to simply refresh /reload the page, if the user didn't check in any of the check box.

now its throwing error. Need to write an else condition for  "if(isset($_POST['disable']))"

Please help.

Comment: or just check if $_POST['users'] is set and an array,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
   .....
   ......
   if(isset($_POST['disable']))
   {
       if(isset($_POST['users'])) {
          foreach ( $_POST['users'] as $userid ) {
            $wpdb->query("UPDATE ".$wpdb->prefix."usercontrol SET disable_status       
            ='disabled' WHERE ID = ".$wpdb->escape($userid));
          } 
       }
   }
?>
```

Form `submit` does reload the page, since in your case it's not bound to an AJAX call. Just added an `isset` that checks for any value for `users` in `$_POST`. Optionally, you can even add an `else` to display an informative message instead of a plain reload.

Comment: Thanku verisimilitude. I added an if condition before the foreach.
if(isset($_POST['users'])){
..foreach
}